# How to use Regex in VBA to split a string into multiple lines, then pick the date from the line containing the word "faxed"

Tags: regex, excel, vba, split

I'm trying to extract some information from the following string:

> 01/05

Comment: Your plan isn't crazy, give it a go - come back with any coding problems you encounter. BTW the Split function in VBA might also be helpful, allows you split a string into array elements. Make a start, you get more help when you have specific coding issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dates in your string are in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, so the regex is written accordingly.

The value is returned as a date, but you can format the cell however you wish.

```
Option Explicit
Function lastFaxedDt(s As String) As Date
    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection
    Const sPat As String = "(\b(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/(?:19\d{2}|[2-9]\d{3})\b)(?=.*?faxed)"

Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Pattern = sPat
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = True
    If .Test(s) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(s)
        lastFaxedDt = CDate(MC(MC.Count - 1))
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Screen shot showing the matched dates:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This isn't an answer it's more a prompt to help you start. It's not using Regex

```
Dim Parts() as string

FullText = "12/07/2018 AB CART 9000341 FAXED TO INSTITUTION 12/10/2018 JT follow up with institution, currently processing, follow up on 12/13 12/13/2018 JR LIB missing, faxed to INSTITUTION, follow up on 12/19 12/18/2018 AB Documents recieved, currently in processing, follow up on 12/22 12/27/2018 LP LIB rejected - Fax illegible, faxed to Institution, follow up on 12/27"

Parts = split(ucase(FullText),"FAXED")

' Now you have 2 parts Parts(0) = Text before word Faxed, Parts(1) = Text after word Faxed

' Following will give you position of rightmost / character in Part(0) - part of the date you want
Pos1 = InStrRev(Part(0),"/")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I'll try building upon this